# Ceiling paint peels while rolling new coat

Tags: ceiling, paint

We are repainting ceiling in the kitchen of a summer house.

First, we scraped a lot of old paint (yellow) and laid joint compound on top of the patches without yellow paint (looks gray in picture)

After that we sanded joint compound, and started applying white latex-based indoors ceiling paint (Behr). When we use roller we see old paint peeling off in patches. There is no peeling of joint compound. The peeling paint is not yellow underneath, so we are peeling off flakes of old yellow paint plus whatever it was painted over.

When we use brush, there is no peeling of the old paint.

Is there a way to fix that?

Our plan so far looks like:

1. wait till new paint dries
2. Try to scrape as much as possible where paint peels
3. Apply joint compound again
4. Let it dry, sand it
5. Paint over using our new white paint

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you won’t like it...

Had this before, and you have to remove the old paint back to a secure, stable layer.

Think yourself lucky - we had to do it on the ceiling of a paper mill.. hundreds of square metres...

Comment: Whats the reasonable way to do that? Scraping with plaster knife doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Sounds like you need more practice or make sure the plaster knife has a good edge, they are what we used - would go through 3 per 12 hour shift then re-sharpen for the next night...